# Member of a list

Tags: plotting

This list is given by
$$
a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3, a_n = 2 \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} + 3a_{n-1}, \text{ for } n>2
$$

Find the 30th element of the list. Print the first 20 elements in a table and sort them in descending order.

Please help me how to begin. I have not been working with this program for a long time. Tell me how to input the given and get the elements in a table in descending order.

Comment: Think about how you would write a factorial function given its recursive definition `n! = n * (n-1)!`.

Comment: Take a look at [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html)/[`ReverseSort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseSort.html), [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) and [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html). If you have tried a few things and you're still unsuccessful, feel free to update the question with some of your attempts.

Comment: Your list seems not to converge. Might it be something like $ a_n = 2 \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} + 3 $?

Answer (score 2):

You can define recursive functions almost exactly the way you have written it in your question:

```
a[n_] := a[n] = 2 a[n - 1]/a[n - 2] + 3 a[n - 1];
a[1] = 2; 
a[2] = 3;
```

Now you can find the 30th element by typing

```
 a[30]
```

and you can find a range of values:

```
a[#]&/@Range[20]
```

Use Sort to sort them.

Comment: Thank you for helping but it does not come correct.I might write it inncorect,so I edited it now.They are subscripts of a.